# Android : How to insert data into database manually

Tags: android

I am working on a project and I have seen various examples on the net where they are demonstrating the insertion of data using Button and all. I want to insert the data manually. I have created the database but insertion part don't know. Below I'm posting the code on which I have worked till now.

VivzHelper.java

```
    import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Message;

import java.util.HashMap;


/**
 * Created by Akash on 3/13/2016.
 */



public class VivzHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "hit_lib1";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "books";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
private static final String UID = "_id";
private static final String Name = "Name";
private static final String ADDRESS = "Address";
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+Name+" VARCHAR(25), "+ADDRESS+" VARCHAR(255));";
private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
private Context context;


public VivzHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context=context;
    appscreator.com.mydatabase.Message.message(context, "Constructor Called");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    try {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        appscreator.com.mydatabase.Message.message(context, "onCreate Called");
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {

        appscreator.com.mydatabase.Message.message(context, "" + e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    try {
        appscreator.com.mydatabase.Message.message(context, "onUpgrade Called");
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        appscreator.com.mydatabase.Message.message(context, "" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}


public void insertEntry()
{

    try
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

       // values.put("Messsage", msg);
        values.put("Name", Name);
        values.put("Address", ADDRESS);

        db.insert("TABLE_NAME ", null, values);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

}
}
```

Main_Activity.java

```
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
VivzHelper vivzHelper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    vivzHelper= new VivzHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase data = vivzHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "I want to insert the data manually" means.

Comment: Just take the code in those tutorials you've found and copy anything in the onClick of the button somewhere else...

Comment: @CommonsWare Suppose I want to insert 5 rows

Comment: Or maybe you should "manually" call your method `insertEntry()`

Comment: @cricket_007 U show me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to insert 5 rows? Use a loop and just call the method you have that inserts data...

```
VivzHelper vivzHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    vivzHelper= new VivzHelper(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        vivzHelper.insertEntry();
    } 
}
```

Comment: and how to delete the inserted record

Comment: that worked like a charm. But how to delete the inserted record

Comment: That wasn't part of your initial question. I suggest following some tutorials on SQLite. Hint: there is a `delete` method in the `SQLiteDatabase` class

Comment: how to insert diffferent rows

Comment: Use different ContentValues in the `db.insert` method

Comment: when i insert 2 rows, it only shows the last row inserted, it doesn't show the 1st row

Comment: I've already answered your question. And you've accepted the answer. If you would like to ask additional questions about how to use Sqlite, please make another post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106151/discussion-between-akashdeep-singh-and-cricket-007).